# Use `less` pager on file with non-standard encoding

Tags: linux, character-encoding, less, pager

I often use the `less` pager to view logfiles. Usually I use `less -F` to follow the progress of the log à la `tail`.

However, some logfiles use national characters in a non-standard encoding (Latin-1, while the system uses UTF-8). Obviously, these will not be displayed correctly.

How can I view such files with `less`?

The only solutions I found:

- Correct the encoding of the file (`recode` or `iconv`). This does not work while the file is still being written, so does not let me use `less -F`. Plus it destroys the logfiles original timestamp, which is bad from an auditing perspective.
- Use a pipe (`recode latin1... |less`). Works for files in progress, but unfortunately then `less -F` does not appear to work (it just does not update; I believe the `recode` process exits once it's done).

Any solution that lets me "tail" a logfile and still shows national characters correctly?

Comment: It looks from `man less` like there is a preprocessor which you could possibly set to fix your encoding.

Comment: @isomorphismes: Yes, `less` does support calling a preprocessor. However, as far as I can tell, the preprocessor reads the input file and creates a new file for `less`, so this would not work for `less -F`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, apparently `less` cannot do this. The part in less' sourcecode that implements the "following" seems to be:

```
A_F_FOREVER:
                        /*
                         * Forward forever, ignoring EOF.
                         */
                        if (ch_getflags() & CH_HELPFILE)
                                break;
                        cmd_exec();
                        jump_forw();
                        ignore_eoi = 1;
                        while (!sigs)
                        {
                                make_display();
                                forward(1, 0, 0);
                        }
                        ignore_eoi = 0;
```

As far as my (limited) knowledge of C goes, this means that if "follow" is activated, less will:

1. seek to the end of input
2. read and update the display in a loop, until Ctrl-C is pressed

If input is a pipel, 1. will not return until the pipe signals EOF. If I use `tail -f xx|less`, the pipe will never signal EOF, so less hangs :-(.

I did however find a way to get what I want:

```
 tail -f inputfile | recode latin1.. > /tmp/tmpfile
```

then

```
less +F /tmp/tmpfile
```

This will work, because it lets less +F work on a real file. It's still somewhat awkward, because `recode` apparently only processes data in blocks of 4096 bytes, but it works...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that `recode` is buffering output in the pipe so output only comes through when the buffer, probably 4K, is full. You can try using the [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) script that comes with [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: No, that is not the problem. The `recode` process simply exits after it detects EOF for the file (after all, it has no way of knowing that the file is still growing); I can confirm this using `ps`. So unbuffer does not help.

Comment: @sleske: Have you tried `tail -f | recode ... | less -F`?

Comment: @Dennis: Actually yes, I tried it, but it didn't help either. It seems `less -F` just plain does not work on pipes. Even `tail -f myfile | less -F` does not work, though in this case both processes remain alive.

Comment: Anyway, +1 for good hints. Even if they didn't work, it's good to know that :-).

Comment: @sleske: By the way, it's `less +F` that follows files like `tail -f` (rather than `less -F`). After some testing, it looks like `recode` is doing some buffering that can't be controlled. This works, but the output is in chunks: `tail -f inputfile | recode ... | less +F`

Comment: @Dennis: Interesting. Your example does not work for me: less just hangs with an emtpy screen, until I press Ctrl-C, then it shows its prompt, but no text.

Comment: To me it seems rather that `less +F` waits for EOF in its input before even showing a prompt. Since that never comes, it appears to hang. Just `tail -f inputfile | less ` works, but it still hangs once I invoke Shift-F (or Shift-G). So it seems what I want just isn't possible with less...

Comment: @sleske: Try `less` in that pipeline without any options: `tail -f inputfile | recode ... | less`. Note: if your logfile is not getting much traffic, it could take a while before the buffer is full and anything is output.

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, I tried that, and it does work, but it's not practical. It will show output, and gives me the less prompt once the first screenful of text has been printed, but scrolling to the end of text still makes less hang until enough fresh text has arrived; and Shift-F or Shift-G still hangs less permanently. So it seems less just can't do what I'd like to do...